# Best python friendly database to use for a 2 billion records

Tags: python, database, nosql

Looking for recommendations for a fast file based database to store some data I'll be loading in to data tables in python3 pandas. Trying to avoid full systems like PostgreSQL,MySQL,MSSQL etc due to the extra daemon setup. Ideally just python scripts and data files loading from dedicated top tier NVME SSD

Will only have a single table with under ten columns but 2 billion records.

Python will regularly be reading through every row.

Comment: Did you try sqlite, which comes with Python?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Vaex](https://vaex.io/docs/index.html). For best For performance you need your data in [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format). For interoperability [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) and for optimizing disk space & faster network i/o: [Apache Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/).